# Using PyOTP library,giving message wrong OTP

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, api

I am using the PyOtp library to generate 6 digits OTP, the backend I am using is python django and the frontend is react.
My issue is that sometimes(not always) when I generate OTP and click to verify OTP, I enter the correct OTP which is generated but it gives me the wrong OTP message and then when I resend OTP, it takes it as correct one. I am not able to figure out why even after entering the correct OTP, it is saying me that it is the wrong OTP. What could be the issue? I am not using the latest version of PyOTP, could that be an issue or it is something related to time sync?
Kindly help me on this.

Thnakyou

I used the library implemented in API created in python and integrated it in react.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example